# Errors were encountered while processing: libcublas E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

```
Preparing to unpack .../88-libcudnn7_7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn7 (7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcudnn7-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../89-libcudnn7-dev_7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn7-dev (7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-POLK4w/29-libcublas10_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends     cuda-10-1     libcudnn7=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1      libcudnn7-dev=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1
```

complete history:

```
486  wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
  487  sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
  488  sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
  489  sudo apt-get update
  490  wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
  491  sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
  492  sudo apt-get update
  493  sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends     cuda-10-1     libcudnn7=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1      libcudnn7-dev=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1
```

I wasn't sure how to find the corresponding version for Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to install TensorRT and CuDNN for the following GPU: GeForce RTX 2070.

Also, before installing the above, I had nvcc, now it is uninstalled and installing it gives me error:

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ nvcc -V

Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-10-1 : Depends: libcublas10 (>= 10.2.1.243) but 10.1.243-3 is to be installed
 libcublas-dev : Depends: libcublas10 (>= 10.2.2.89) but 10.1.243-3 is to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now even my nvidia-smi is not working

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

System is:

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ uname -a
Linux mona 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Additionally trying:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-8 libaccinj64-10.1 libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcublaslt10 libcudart10.1 libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-10.1 libcupti-dev libcupti-doc libcupti10.1 libcurand10 libcusolver10 libcusolvermg10
  libcusparse10 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libllvm9:i386 libncurses5 libnppc10 libnppial10 libnppicc10 libnppicom10 libnppidei10 libnppif10 libnppig10 libnppim10 libnppist10
  libnppisu10 libnppitc10 libnpps10 libnvblas10 libnvgraph10 libnvidia-common-440 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvjpeg10 libnvrtc10.1 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm3 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++-8-dev
  libstdc++6:i386 libthrust-dev libtinfo5 libvdpau-dev libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
  nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcublas10
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcublas10
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.
90 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/42.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 35.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 261464 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcublas10_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcublas10 (10.2.2.89-1) over (10.1.243-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas10_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvblas.so.10', which is also in package libnvblas10:amd64 10.1.243-3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas10_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```